# Recoding multiple race variables into a single race variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to recode multiple race variables into a single race variable. The different variables are `RaceVar1: Asian` `RaceVar2: AIAN` `RaceVar3: Black` `RaceVar4: Native Hawaiian` `RaceVar5: White`. Variables are ticked off with a `1` if participants chose that race, and `0` if they didn't. I would like to create a new race variable that condenses these variables into one, as well as assess for if someone ticked off multiple races.

I am able to do this in SAS however I need to do this in R and am unsure how to perform the same task. SAS code below

```
data want;
set have;
length race $40;
if sum(of r_s_q61___1 - r_s_q61___5) > 1 then race='More than one race';
else if r_s_q61___2 then race='American Indian or Alaska Native';
else if r_s_q61___1 then race='Asian';
else if r_s_q61___5 then race='White';
else if r_s_q61___3 then race='Black or African American';
else if r_s_q61___4 then race='Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander';
else race='Unknown';
run;
```

I'm not sure where to start other than I believe maybe using `rowSums()` and `ifthen()` within a `mutate()` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! `mutate` and `ifelse` are your friends here. With `dplyr` though we've also got a neat function called `case_when` that lets us nest a bunch of `ifelse` statements simultaneously.

```r
library(dplyr)
data.frame(`RaceVar1`=c(1,0,0,0,0,1),
           `RaceVar2`=c(0,1,0,0,0,0),
           `RaceVar3`=c(0,0,1,0,0,0),
           `RaceVar4`=c(0,0,0,1,0,0),
           `RaceVar5`=c(0,0,0,0,1,0),
           `RaceVar6`=c(0,0,0,0,0,1)) %>%
  mutate(more_than_one=rowSums(.)) %>%
  mutate(Race=ifelse(
    more_than_one>1,
    'More than one race',
    case_when(
      RaceVar1 == 1 ~ "RaceVar1: Asian",
      RaceVar2 == 1 ~ "RaceVar2: AIAN",
      RaceVar3 == 1 ~ "RaceVar3: Black",
      RaceVar4 == 1 ~ "RaceVar4: Native Hawaiian",
      RaceVar5 == 1 ~ "RaceVar5: White"
    )
  ))
```

```
  RaceVar1 RaceVar2 RaceVar3 RaceVar4 RaceVar5 RaceVar6 more_than_one                      Race
1        1        0        0        0        0        0             1           RaceVar1: Asian
2        0        1        0        0        0        0             1            RaceVar2: AIAN
3        0        0        1        0        0        0             1           RaceVar3: Black
4        0        0        0        1        0        0             1 RaceVar4: Native Hawaiian
5        0        0        0        0        1        0             1           RaceVar5: White
6        1        0        0        0        0        1             2        More than one race
```